# create a table sorted by attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt and i've been struggling to find a solution to this, I need to create a table where my xml document sorted by the attribute "level" (niveau here) and then in alphabetical order

here is the xml document (it's in french in case you're wondering)

```
   <dico
       xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='dico.xsd'>
       <mot niveau="2">arbre</mot>
       <mot niveau="2">jeu</mot>
       <mot niveau="3">essence</mot>
       <mot niveau="5">convalescence</mot>
       <mot niveau="5">mot-valise</mot>
       <mot niveau="1">pain</mot>
       <mot niveau="4">maintenance</mot>
   
   </dico>
```

and here is my xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Dictionnaire</title>
            </head>
            <body>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="dico/mot">
                    <xsl:sort select="@niveau"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="."/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>



            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="mot">
        <table border="4" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="2" width="80%">
            <tr>
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width: 33%" />
                    <col style="width: 33%" />
                    <col style="width: 33%" />
                </colgroup>
                <td>
                    le mot est : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
           
                <td>   
                    niveau : <xsl:value-of select="@niveau"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>`
```

Comment: Please add the expected result to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/dico">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Dictionnaire</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="4" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="2" width="80%">
                    <thead style="background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>mot</th>
                            <th>niveau</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="mot">
                            <xsl:sort select="@niveau"/>
                            <xsl:sort select="."/>
                            <tr>
                                <td>le mot est : <xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                                <td>niveau : <xsl:value-of select="@niveau"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```